# how to add html and css in my home page which is written in nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have made a page using next js and now I have to add design in that page which is written in html css and I don't know how to put tags in nextjs ..where to put tags?

I have tried taking particular tags and putting it in style jsx but it didn't work

THIS IS MY HOME PAGE WHERE I HAVE TO ADD THE DESIGN

```
import Link from 'next/link'
import Header from '../components/Header'
import Footer from '../components/Footer';

const Home = () => (
 <div>

        <Header/>

        <p>This is the home page</p>
        <Link href="/team">Team</Link>
        <Link href="/courses">Courses</Link>
        <Footer/>
 </div>
```

Just help me by telling me where to add

Comment: Can you show us your `style.jsx` that you tried?

Comment: Also have you tried these examples from the docs? https://github.com/zeit/next.js/#css

Comment: @BlunderingPhilospher no I didnt tried those examples but I studied that lessons provided by thw way I have a design of website of my own but that is iin html css and I want that html css to use in next.js .

Comment: I know how to add css but no idea about html tags ..The body tag and the tags inside that how to write in here ? I am stuck there ``

Answer (score 1):

You have 3 options.

- ### Option 1

Use `Head` in your page like this:

```
import Link from 'next/link'
import Head from 'next/head'
import Header from '../components/Header'
import Footer from '../components/Footer';

const Home = () => (
 <div>
  <Head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/style.css"/>
  </Head>

  <Header/>

  <p>This is the home page</p>
  <Link href="/team">Team</Link>
  <Link href="/courses">Courses</Link>
  <Footer/>
</div>
```

notice `import Head from 'next/head'` and also use of `head` tag. You can put all head tag there like `title, meta, link` etc. The style will be available and effect this component.

- ### Option 2:

use `jsx` like this

```
import Link from 'next/link'
import Header from '../components/Header'
import Footer from '../components/Footer';

const Home = () => (
<div>
  <Header/>

  <p>This is the home page</p>
  <Link href="/team">Team</Link>
  <Link href="/courses">Courses</Link>
  <Footer/>
  <style jsx>{`
    p{
      color: red
     }
   `}</style>
 </div>
```

but in this case, your style will be `scoped` it means it will be only available for this component. So you need to do the same for your `Header` and `Footer` component. But you can add `<style jsx global>...</style>` to make it global.

- ### Option 3:

Use the option 1 (`import Head from 'next/head'` and use `<Head>...</Head>`) in `pages/_app.js` and then it will be shared between all pages.

---

#### Note:

Make sure if you use option 1 or 3, you can put your `css` file in `/static/style.css` (`static` is a special directory in root of your `next.js` project) file and then you can have access to the file like this(No matter where are you going to use it. the address will be always like this):

```
<Head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/style.css"/>
</Head>
```